# AWS Elastic Beanstalk HTTP to HTTPS not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, https, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, cloudflare, aws-application-load-balancer

I have a elasticbeanstalk (EB) application and when I go to its HTTP url (the default) I can open the app!

I want 2 things:

1. Open the url on HTTPS
2. Instead of having the EB generated random URL/endpoint - I want to host it on route53 on my own chosen domain.

I cannot get 1 nor 2 to work.

For 1, these are my load balancer configurations:
[image]

The https is pointing to this target group (which is pointing to the ec2 instance at port 80):
[image]

Now, in my EB configurations I have this:

[image]

Both the listeners are enabled.

Now when I open my EB endpoint I get:

[image]

I clicked on the "Not Secure" and saw that it was saying "Certificate invalid"

[image]

[image]

Even when I open the ALB endpoint (DNS) directly in browser I get same "Not Secure" and "Invalid Cert" like above^^

So, I am not sure why this is happening even though I have the right ACM cert for *.example.com also attached to the listener.

I also have port 80 and port 443 opened both on instance and load balancer security group.

Once, I can figure out 1, then I also want to figure out 2.

For 2, I have a route53 zone for example.com and the ACM cert is for *.example.com

The domain I want the EB endpoint to point to is eb.example.com

So in Route53 I created an A record for the ALIAS to point to the load balancer of my EB and its endpoint (DNS).

but when I open the eb.example.com I see:
[image]

Now this could be happening because https not working on the original EB endpoint (1) but I also tried CNAME and it still didnt work.

what am I missing?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first issue, the browser saying the connection is not private, is due to you going to the Elastic Beanstalk URL, instead of your custom domain name. The SSL certificate is for your custom domain name. The browser will only accept the SSL certificate when the domain name in the certificate matches the domain name in the browser's address bar. You really needed to get the second issue (custom domain name) working before you tried to setup the SSL stuff.

Regarding the second issue, the `DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN` error means your web browser can't find any DNS records for that domain name. That indicates there is something wrong with your Route53 configuration. I would start by going [here](https://dnschecker.org/), and checking if the domain name can be found.

---

From your update, I would note that you also appear to be using Cloudflare. Cloudflare is a DNS service, so you probably need to update the DNS records in your Cloudflare account and stop trying to use Route53. You can't have two authoritative DNS servers for the same domain name at the same time, and Cloudflare appears to be the authoritative DNS server for your domain name. The SSL certificate you are using also appears to be a Cloudflare origin certificate, which will never work directly in a web browser anyway. The Cloudflare origin certificate will only work for Cloudflare origin requests, when you go to a domain name that is proxied by Cloudflare (orange cloud icon on the DNS record in Cloudflare).

Comment: this is the exact reason why it was not working. I put the records in cloudflare and my domain is not working. thank you!